# Smartparens slurping across fluent call chains in php-mode

Tags: smartparens, php-mode

I have not been able to find a solution to this frustrating problem. Here is the situation and my questions are at the end:

Given code that looks similar to this:

```php
$this->hello()->wootFluent()->patterns();
```

I want to wrap the whole chain in parens, this could be just parens or maybe another function call. So I start with my cursor, `|`, at the front:

```php
|$this->hello()->wootFluent()->patterns();
```

I `insert-parentheses` with `M-(`

```php
()|$this->hello()->wootFluent()->patterns();
```

Then I `sp-slurp-hybrid-sexp` with `C-S-right` after moving the cursor within the parens:

```php
($this)->hello()->wootFluent()->patterns();
```

One more time:

```php
($thishello())->->wootFluent()->patterns();
```

And now my chain is illegal; fubar.

Is there a way to configure smartparens to include the `->` in its slurping? Am I using the right smartparens command for slurping? I would like to make successive slurp commands so that I will end up with a structure like this:

```php
($this->hello()->wootFluent()->patterns());
```

Comment: Welcome! Would encircling the region you want (set-mark-command) and press "(" work for you?

Comment: There are workarounds but slurping and barfing allow a more interactive way of structuring. For example what if my desired form is `otherFunction($this->hello()->wootFluent())->patterns();` Then I can slurp with `C-<right>` until I'm happy.

Comment: Hi!  Did you try adding a post-handler?